# How to Convert Vector number 5-digit number into date format

Tags: date, conversion

I am trying to convert the date format something like 10/03/2018 to 43376 in shell scripting, this can be done by using format cell option as the number in excel. How can do it in shell scripting?

Comment: What is 43376? What time does it represent, what's the conversion? https://www.epochconverter.com

Comment: 43376 is the value of the date column in SQL table. If we convert that number in excel by using format cell option as a date it will convert as 10/03/2018.

Comment: But what is the number? It's not seconds since 1/1/1970, or days since (whenever). I can't guess what the number represents, so I can't give you a conversion function to use in a Linux shell (also: is this bash?)

Comment: @michael Number represents the date in a table, by that date all the columns values will be added by the one of the application but that application not using date format(like 10/03/2018),instead date format application inserting the values as 43376.(yes this is bash)

Comment: `43376*86400` in unix epoch seconds is 10/03/2008 which is oddly exactly a decade off the example date value (days-since-epoch comes up in Samba and LDAP contexts). but that's just a guess

Comment: @thrig that's the number of days since 1st January 1900, 1-indexed and incorrectly considering 1900 a leap year. See my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485068/313992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the info on this [blog](http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/excel-date-conversion-days-from-1900) is true, this formula should do it:

```
date_to_msidx(){ echo $(( $(TZ=UTC date -d "$1" +%s) / 86400 + 25569)); }

date_to_msidx 10/03/2018
43376
date_to_msidx 07/05/1998
35981
```

This is ["The 1900 Date System"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel) of Microsoft; days since 1st January 1900 starting from 1, but *incorrectly* considering 1900 a leap year (one day longer than in reality).

The formula first use `date +%s` to convert it to Unix time (~secs since 1970/01/01), divides it by the number of seconds in a day (86400), then adds the number of days from 1900/01/01 to 1970/01/01 (25569) precalculated using the system above.

This is assuming GNU date; adapting it for other system/languages is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I am able to convert the date to the number but it not giving the correct date with that. If I change it as                                                                                      
date_to_msidx(){ echo $(( $(date -d "$1" +%s) / 86400 + 25569)); }                                             It is giving the accurate dates. Even I calculated the days between 1900 to 1970 it is coming only 2567 days but how 2569/70 is correct I am not able to figure out.

Comment: You're right, it was a stupid noob mistake (I forgot that `date` is also considering the timezone, it should be `TZ=UTC date`). As to why it's 25569 instead of 25567, it's +1 because it starts from 1, not from 0, and +1 because it's wrongly considering 1900 a leap year (with february 1900 having 29 instead of 28 days).